# Write a script which decodes the Following JSON String. Any idea how to get pass the Address part?

Tags: php, json

im trying to do this json decoding my professor suggested i try, but i cant seem to pass the address part. Any ideas?

```
{"fname": "Nick", "mname": "F.", "lname": "Delos Reyes", "birthday": "1995-04-01", "address": { "Country": "America", "state": "New York" }}
```

Expected output:

```
Name : Nick F. Delos Reyes
Birthday : 1995-04-01 
Address  :Caramoran, New York
```

Comment: What have you tried, precisely? Always shoe your code. This will show you the general approach: [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: P.s. "Caramoran" doesn't appear anywhere in the JSON so it's unclear how you expect that to be in the output.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to it. Following is an example to parse the name.

```php
$array = json_decode('{"fname": "Nick", "mname": "F.", "lname": "Delos Reyes", "birthday": "1995-04-01", "address": { "Country": "America", "state": "New York" }}', true);
$name = [$array['fname'], $array['mname'], $array['lname']];
$outputName = 'Name:' . implode(' ', $name);
```

It uses `json_decode()` to convert the JSON to an associative array. It then put the name parts in an array. It uses `implode()` to join the name parts into a string.